# Get location in a webview (UPDATED)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I´m having one problem with my "app". I made a webview which loads the website of the shop where I work. When i go to the location section and touch the map, if i havent got the Maps app it loads it on the webview. The problem is that i can´t get it to get my location.

I want to know what can i do to fix that. I cant find the answer in stackoverflow, other post dont answer it so that´s why i´m making this post

***Here is part ofthe .java Class of the app (UPDATED)***

```
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationDatabasePath( this.getFilesDir().getPath() );
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin,
                                                           final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                final boolean remember = true;
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this);
                builder.setTitle("Locations");
                builder.setMessage(origin + " Would like to use your Current Location").setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Allow",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                // origin, allow, remember
                                callback.invoke(origin, true, remember);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Don't Allow",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                        // origin, allow, remember
                                        callback.invoke(origin, false, remember);
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
```

[It "searchs" the location but never found it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfqGK.png)

Answer (score 2):

- JavaScript must be enabled in the `WebView`, using
  `WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` The app needs permission
  ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION The `WebView`must use a custom `WebChromeClient`
  which implements
  `WebChromeClient.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt()`. This method
  is called by the WebView to obtain permission to disclose the user's
  location to JavaScript. (In the case of the browser, we show a prompt
  to the user.) The default implementation does nothing, so permission
  is never obtained and the location is never passed to JavaScript.`webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { 
  public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
  callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
  } 
  });`

Geolocation uses databases to persist cached positions and permissions between sessions. The location of the database is set using WebSettings.setGeolocationDatabasePath(...). If the location of the database is not set, the persistent storage will not be available, but Geolocation will continue to function correctly otherwise. To set the location of the databases, use ...

```
webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath( context.getFilesDir().getPath() );
```

Comment: i pasted ALL the code. Please check what are you saying because i know i can make faults but the things you are pointing are there.

Answer (score 0):

Si tú intención es mostrar una ubicación fija, podés hacerlo de las siguientes maneras:

**Ejemplo 1**

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if(url.contains("geo:")) {
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(url);
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                      startActivity(mapIntent);
                }
            return true;
        }  
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
```

**Ejemplo 2**

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355");
```

Tené en cuenta que la aplicación tiene que tener permisos de acceso a internet y el Webview tiene que tener habilitado el uso de Javascript.

Comment: Lucas, que tal!

La muestra, el tema es que quiero que la persona pueda ubicarse desde ella asi no debo llevarlos a un navegador si no llegar a tener maps, quiero que el webview lo maneje. He logrado obtener una notificacion cuando toco el "buscar" pero el tema es que no me da el permiso de localizacion. Ahora actualizo el codigo y muestro

Comment: Ahi actualice la clase java